# Angular frontend (using proxy) is requesting wrong back end url

Tags: angular, proxy

My app is an angular 11.0.6 as a front end deployed on IIS and configured for `mywebsite.com` (port 80).
The backend is a dotnet core web api deployed on IIS and configured for `my.server.ip.address:190`.
Both are i the same prod server that has the ip address : my.server.ip.address
When I hit a button (example register action) that should call an end point, I see that the URL of the call is  `mywebsite.com/api/register` but it should be `my.server.ip.address:190/api/register`.

Here my front end configuration :

proxy.config.json :

```
  "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://my.server.ip.address:190",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mywebsite:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mywebsite:build:production",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            }
          }
```

Build command on Azure DevOps:

```
    - task: Npm@1
      displayName: npm Build
      inputs:
        command: 'custom'
        customCommand: 'run build --prod --env=prod'
```

Comment: "_I see that the URL of the call is_" If you are talking about the chrome/ff dev tools, they won't show you the proxied address.

Comment: Oh, ok thanks for the clarification.
The error is 404 Not Found, may be it is an issue with the fire wall?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo error in your config key =>  "proxyConfig": "**src/proxy.conf.json**"  check file name is it conf or config